# how to use character in array on switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

when I compile the program it says 'd' is not an int so if anyone has idea how to change it to an int or make it work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    if(k==2)
    {
        cout << "we have 3 main sub companies and other 2 companies that are growing\n";
        cout << "the 3 main sub companies are\n";
        cout << "        a-Aegre Food and Drinks\n";
        cout << "        b-Future Tech\n";
        cout << "        c-Hope Energy\n";
        char d[]={'a','b','c'};
        int d[0]=1,d[1]=2,d[2]=3;
        cout << "In which one of our companies do you want to invest plase enter the letters befor them ";
        cin  >>d;
        switch(d)//here it says d is n't an int//
        {
            case a:cout <<"we have 5 bonds";
            case b:cout <<"we have 3 bonds";
            case c:cout <<"we have 2 bonds";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, the error does not say "d is not an `int`". Please post the complete error message

Comment: `char d; cin >> d; switch (d) { case 'a': ...; break;  case 'b': ...; }`

Comment: There's a lot more to [that error stack](https://godbolt.org/z/f9jjhGbME) than you're letting on.

Comment: What is your understanding of what `d` is? Your code looks like you are unsure about it. It declares it as an array of `char` (`char d[]={'a','b','c'};`) , then as an array of `int` (with weird size and init, .... and several times...., `int d[0]=1,d[1]=2,d[2]=3;`). But I feel that it is not what you think/intend.

Comment: i want to map char to int

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to solve this problem without an array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    if(k==2)
    {
        cout << "We have 3 main sub-companies and other 2 companies that are growing.\n";
        cout << "The 3 main sub-companies are\n";
        cout << "        a-Aegre Food and Drinks\n";
        cout << "        b-Future Tech\n";
        cout << "        c-Hope Energy\n";

        char d;
        cout << "In which one of our companies do you want to invest? Please enter the letters before them: ";
        cin >> d;

        switch(d)
        {
            case 'a':
                cout << "We have 5 bonds";
                break;
            case 'b':
                cout << "We have 3 bonds";
                break;
            case 'c':
                cout << "We have 2 bonds";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid input!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

A `char` is an integer type, which can be used in a `switch` statement.

Note that I am using [character literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) in the `case` labels of the `switch` statement. Also, if you don't want to fall through to the next case, you must use `break` after every case in the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to make `d` an array of characters, an array of integers and a single value all at the same time? I think what you actually want to do is read a single character and compare it in a switch? You don't need an array at all:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    if(k==2)
    {
        cout << "we have 3 main sub companies and other 2 companies that are growing\n";
        cout << "the 3 main sub companies are\n";
        cout << "        a-Aegre Food and Drinks\n";
        cout << "        b-Future Tech\n";
        cout << "        c-Hope Energy\n";
        char company;
        cout << "In which one of our companies do you want to invest plase enter the letters befor them ";
        cin  >>company;
        switch(company)
        {
            case 'a':cout <<"we have 5 bonds";
                break;
            case 'b':cout <<"we have 3 bonds";
                break;
            case 'c':cout <<"we have 2 bonds";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note you need a `break` between your cases otherwise `a` will trigger all three cases.

If what you were trying to do was map a company letter to a number then a `std::map` is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin >> k;
    if(k==2)
    {
        cout << "we have 3 main sub companies and other 2 companies that are growing\n";
        cout << "the 3 main sub companies are\n";
        cout << "        a-Aegre Food and Drinks\n";
        cout << "        b-Future Tech\n";
        cout << "        c-Hope Energy\n";
        std::map<char, int> companies = {{'a', 1}, {'b', 2}, {'c', 3}};
        char company;
        cout << "In which one of our companies do you want to invest plase enter the letters befor them ";
        cin  >>company;
        auto companyNumber = companies.find(company);
        if (companyNumber == companies.end())
        {
            cout << "invalid company\n";
            return 1;
        }
        switch(companyNumber->second)
        {
            case 1:cout <<"we have 5 bonds";
                break;
            case 2:cout <<"we have 3 bonds";
                break;
            case 3:cout <<"we have 2 bonds";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`d` is a character array, you can change elements like this,
`d[0] = '1', d[1] = '2', d[2] = '3';`

But you can't do it like this,
`int d[0]=1,d[1]=2,d[2]=3;`

because `d` is already declared as a character array. You can't declare it in another variable.

Some Examples:

```
char d[]={'a','b','c'}; // char array
    d[0]='1',d[1]='2',d[2]='3'; // update char array       
    cin  >>d[0]; // you can also take input like this (cin >> d[0]) or (cin >> d[1]) or (cin >> d[2]).
    switch(d[0]) // pass input 
    {
        case 'a':cout <<"we have 5 bonds";
        case 'b':cout <<"we have 3 bonds";
        case 'c':cout <<"we have 2 bonds";
    }
```